# Unwanted current thru transistor

Tags: transistors

I have the following circuit:

[image: circuit]

What the circuit should do:

1. When switch SW1 is open, D1 is OFF and D2 is ON
2. When switch SW1 is closed, D1 is ON and D2 is OFF

The circuit works almost well. The only problem is, when switch is open, D1 instead of being completely off, it's slightly lit. At some point, I've remove Q1 and D2 completely, but D1 was still slightly lit.

What can be the problem ? Any ideas on how can I fix it ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> What can be the problem ?

With SW1 open, the path for Q2 emitter-base current is through R2, **D1** and R3.

> Any ideas on how can I fix it ?

[image]

The above circuit uses one less transistor but consumes more than twice as much power when L1 is on than when L2 is on.  It would be straightforward to add another transistor and resistor to "fix" that.  The value of R3 should be determined experimentally.

Comment: I'm new to electronics, so this might be a stupid question: if the current flows in the PNP transistor from emitter to base (the base is pulled to ground) wouldn't this actually allow current to also flow from emitter to collector ?

Comment: @NicolaeSurdu, when SW1 is open, D2 is on because Q2 is on.  However, Q2 is on because there is a path for base current *through* D1.  Since there is current through D1, D1 is not off but is instead, slightly lit.  That was the question you asked:  "why is D1 slightly lit when SW1 is open", correct?

Comment: Ah, ok, sorry... I was very tired last night and I wasn't thinking straight... :(.  Any idea on how can I fix that, other than Gustavo Corona's solution ?

Comment: @NicolaeSurdu, see updated answer.

Comment: @NicolaeSurdu, I see that you are planning to use a GPIO pin of a Rasberry-Pi in place of the switch.  The circuit in my update is not suitable for that; the current into the pin will probably not be safe.  You have to be careful to protect the pin from excessive voltage and current.

Comment: Thank you for the update and for the heads up! I'll continue to search for a better, working designs. I realize that this is a good way to learn. But just to clarify something: in order to determine that my design is safe for Raspberry-Pi, I should measure the current across the switch and see if it's in specs, right ?

Comment: @NicolaeSurdu, (1) *replace* the switch with an ammeter to find the current the pin will see when the "switch" is on.  (2) *replace* the switch with a voltmeter to find the voltage the pin will see when the "switch" is off.

Comment: As shown it requires the Pi to sink somewhat over 15 mA, which you'll have to check the Pi datasheet to see if its okay or not. Also, because of the 9 V supply it probably won't shut fully off when the Pi output goes high. Replace the switch with a (logic-level, n-channel) FET with gate driven from the Pi's output (high for closed, low for open) to avoid both problems.

Comment: Also because of the 9 V supply, if you drive the node at the L1 cathode directly with a microcontroller output, you're likely to violate the micro's abs max pin voltage and drive current back in to its output when you try to turn L1 off.

Answer (score 2):

*"What the circuit should do:*

1. *When switch SW1 is open, D1 is OFF and D2 is ON*
2. *When switch SW1 is closed, D1 is ON and D2 is OFF"*

This problem specification can be implemented with single-pole, double-throw switch, and only passive components, since the current which drives the LEDs can just flow through the switch.

Transistors are used when the switching signal originates from a device which doesn't have the current driving ability to drive the load directly, but has enough driving ability to drive the base of a transistor.

"I must solve this with two bipolar transistors" is academics, not engineering.

Comment: In real application, the switch will be replaced by a GPIO pin from Raspberry-Pi, maybe I should have mentioned that in the question ...

Answer (score 1):

I created the following variation using an NPN for Q2 and simulated it using Multisim and it seems to work. I don't know if it's an option for you to change Q2 to an NPN but you could try it.

[image]

Basically what happens is when the switch is open, R3 and R2 form a voltage divider with a voltage of 2.23V, enough to BIAS Q2, and drive D1. All the current is following into Q2's emmiter, so you are not pulling current out of Q1's base, hence you can't drive D2.

Comment: That looks like a solution :). I'll try it out tonight. Thank you!

Comment: I've tried it but didn't managed to make it work. By playing with R3, either both where lit at the same time, or D2 was lit on SW1 closed, but D1 remained on. PS: I'm new to electronics, and I don't get the role of R3 :(